# simple jax-ws-webservice with basic authentication

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, basic-authentication

I have a simple WSDL for a webservice. With wsimport I generated the java wrappers. And I have implemented the generated interface in a class "MyService". Then I publish this webservice with the built-in features of Java6:

```
MyService myService = new MyService();
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:80/servicetest/services/MyServiceINSoap", myService);
```

When I let this code run, everything works perfect - I am able to connect to the service with a soapclient and can execute the methods.

Now I want the built-in webserver of the javavm to use basic authentication - so the client has to provide an userid and a password. How do I accomplish this? Is this possible? Or do I need an application server (tomcat, jboss, whatever...)?

I have searched for some time but only found solutions for webservice which are hosted in an application server.

Many thanks in advance!

erwrock

Comment: When you say "basic authentication", are you referring to the HTTP BASIC auth type that's defined in web.xml, or basic as in simple username/password pair?

Comment: HTTP BASIC auth.
An I use the built-in webserver of the jre - therefore no web.xml.

however I found this site:
https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/03/jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers.html

answers my question and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here:

https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/03/jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers.html

after hours of trial-and-error finally the right searchwords in google :)

Answer (score 1):

As I found your answer I was quite relieved because I searched hours for a solution. But as I tried to follow your link I noticed that the page is not available any longer. Fortunately, I found the old version with the help of the Wayback Machine (https://archive.org/web/). Although, this article is great I had some problems with getting the basic auth to work at the client side. In the end I got it working with the help of java.net.Authenticator. Here are the code snippets which I hope to be useful for others.

Server:

```
javax.xml.ws.Endpoint serverEndpoint = Endpoint.create(new MyService());

com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);

com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpContext httpContext = server.createContext("/myservice");

server.start();

AuthenticatorServer authenticatorServer = new AuthenticatorServer("myRealm", "myName", "myPwd");

httpContext.setAuthenticator(authenticatorServer);  

serverEndpoint.publish(httpContext);
```

Where AuthenticatorServer is:

```
private static class AuthenticatorServer extends com.sun.net.httpserver.BasicAuthenticator {

    private final String user;
    private final String pwd;

    public AuthenticatorServer(String realm, String user, String pwd) {
        super(realm);
        this.user = user;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkCredentials(String userNameInput, String passwordInput) {

        return StringUtils.equals(user, userNameInput) && StringUtils.equals(pwd, passwordInput);

    }

}
```

And on the Client side:

```
AuthenticatorClient authenticatorClient = new AuthenticatorClient("myName", "myPwd");

Authenticator.setDefault(authenticatorClient);

javax.xml.namespace.QName qName = new QName(namespaceURI, WS_SERVICE_NAME);
java.net.URL wsdlAddress = new URL(namespaceURI + WS_SERVICE_NAME + "?wsdl");

MyService service =(Service.create(wsdlAddress, qName)).getPort(MyService.class);
```

Where AuthenticatorClient is:

```
private static class AuthenticatorClient extends java.net.Authenticator {

    private final String user;
    private final String pwd;

    public AuthenticatorClient(String user, String pwd) {
        this.user = user;
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(user, pwd == null ? null : pwd.toCharArray()));
    }

}
```